# Selectize load function is not triggered on typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have the following selectize element:

```
$('#my_selectize').selectize({
            valueField: 'value',
            labelField: 'text',
            options: [{'value':1,'text':'abc','inn':123}],
            render: {
            option: function(data, escape) 
            {
                //return ....
            },
            load: function(query, callback)
            {
                if (!query.length) // breakpoint not triggered
                    return callback(); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{% url my_url %}',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {q: query},
                    error: function() { callback(); },
                    success: function(res) {
                        callback(JSON.parse(vendor_options_json.f));
                    }
                });
            }
        }});
```

According to the [docs](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/), once the user starts typing, I should see my browser stop at the breakpoint put on the commented line with if-condition (if (!query.length)). This doesn't happen. Is there something I misunderstood about it? As far as I understand, load-method is responsible for fetching from server-side the options that match what the user is typing.

Comment: Your snippet has an error in "render" property (remove it, or close it properly). Fix that and it should be working.

Comment: Great !!! didn't notice that, thank you A bit off-topic, but if I understand correctly, initial options are never used, because as the user starts typing, the option set is updated from server-side. Then why initialize it from the outset?

Comment: I'm not sure about options, but you can use preload: true, to populate items on empty search.